# Verilog how to use input and output of submodule inside always block

Tags: verilog

I have a problem (due to lack of understanding) where I have built a module in another file and wish to have my higher level (not necessarily the top level) module use it by providing inputs, and getting the output of the module. Below is a snippet of the code in its simplified form to illustrate my problem.

```
module translate_packet_data(rx_packet, packet_size, do_analysis, output_ascii);

reg [7:0] gps_utc_hour;
reg [7:0] gps_utc_min;
reg [7:0] gps_utc_sec;
reg [31:0] gps_utc_milli;

wire [3:0] utc_hour_hundreds_w,utc_hour_tens_w,utc_hour_ones_w;
reg [3:0] utc_hour_hundreds,utc_hour_tens,utc_hour_ones;


binary8_to_BCD utc_hour_BCD(
    .binary(gps_utc_hour), 
    .Hundreds(utc_hour_hundreds_w), 
    .Tens(utc_hour_tens_w),
    .Ones(utc_hour_ones_w)
);

always @ (posedge do_analysis) begin
 //Do all my logic stuff
    gps_utc_hour = rx_packet[pointer-:8];
 //more logic stuff, but thats besides the point

 //Here is where illegal stuff happen that I don't know how to get around, even though it is synthesizable, the simulation reveals it is wrong
    utc_hour_tens = utc_hour_tens_w;
    utc_hour_tens = utc_hour_tens + 48;
    reg_output_ascii = {reg_output_ascii, utc_hour_tens};

end
```

As you can probably see from my snippet, utc_hour_tens_w will not have been resolved yet and I will get XXXX from simulation. So my question is how do I get around this problem if I want to maintain all translation logic inside this module? (And yes, I know this code as presented will not work, it is a rough copy/paste job of the relevant parts to the question, full code has some 600 lines you all don't want to see)

The goal is primarily to take a packet, extract the meaningful portion, convert it to BCD, then convert it to ASCII and store it into an output register that will be fed to a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your sensitivity list is wrong.

```
always @ (posedge do_analysis) begin
 //Do all my logic stuff
    gps_utc_hour = rx_packet[pointer-:8];
 //more logic stuff, but thats besides the point

 //Here is where illegal stuff happen that I don't know how to get around, even though it is synthesizable, the simulation reveals it is wrong
    utc_hour_tens = utc_hour_tens_w;
    utc_hour_tens = utc_hour_tens + 48;
    reg_output_ascii = {reg_output_ascii, utc_hour_tens};

end
```

If this is just intended to be a combinational block (not a clocked sequential logic), then you should just use the inferred sensitivity list `always @*`. This will make sure that utc_hour_tens_w is included in the sensitivity, and your output will update as soon as `utc_hour_tens_w` does.

If you're trying to prevent the outputs from changing when `do_analysis` is low, then make an if condition inside the block, don't try to control combinational logic by messing with the sensitivity list.

Comment: Just to be clear, does adding the * mean that anytime a signal changes, the always block will be executed from the start of the block? I think this implies I would need additional logic to ensure I only want a specific portion of code to run when the related change is detected (which would be alot of work, but doable given the size of this). I already mentioned adding a time delay to let values stabalize as a temporary solution, but am not sure if that is safe or not.

Comment: @* is the equivalent of writing a list of all signals that are sources to the block, so it re-evaluates the block every time any of those signals changes. This is used for purely combinational blocks that don't need to retain any state (like a group of AND/OR gates) I don't understand what 'additional logic' you think you need. If you want to latch some values so that they do not change when the inputs change, then you need to design a synchronous block with a clock signal. Using # delays is a bad idea, they should really never be used when modeling hardware (only for testbenches).

Comment: My logic is mostly extracting various information from a packet and storing them in a register. Once I am done going through the packet, all the registers are inputted into their respective modules and give me an output in a more useful binary format. The outputs will not all be stabilized at the same time, hence why I want to add a delay to wait for them too to stabilize. Once all are stable, I can then do bit manipulation and concatenate them all into a single register. This is all done inside the same always block. Should I have done this using clocks and state machines instead?

Comment: @fysloc - Yes, you should use clocks and state machines. The problem with delays is that they only have an effect in simulation, not on actual hardware (where delays are defined by RC parasitics and transistor delays, and highly variable). The proper method to do any kind of timing control/synchronization is with clocked logic. It's up to you if what you have is 'good enough' for your purposes, but if this is at all important or going into a larger design than I would try to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attempting to assign a register twice in a single sequential block, the second time with data derived from itself. You might try replacing the pair of `utc_hour_tens = ...` assignments with `utc_hour_tens <= utc_hour_tens+48`

Comment: There's not anything inherently wrong with assigning the same value twice inside an always block, provided that you're using blocking assignments, as is done in the code.

Comment: There was a problem in my code on that statement and I minimized it, but regardless, the wire hasn't been resolved yet. I found a temporary solution to add a fixed delay inside the logic that will allow the outputs of the modules to be resolved before using them and it works, but is probably not the safest method.

Comment: @fysloc A "fixed delay" is not synthesizable, so you may end up with a simulation that works fine and hardware that fails. If you intend to synthesize your code you really need to think in terms of hardware. When you say "the always block will be executed" leads me to believe that you need to take a step back and learn how HDLs get translated into hardware.